# dateadd in postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have this student_loan table and would like to know those that have finished early.

```
student-id, loan_amount, date_given, terms, last_paymnt
xxxx        xxxx         04/03/2010   36    08/09/2012
xxxx        xxxx         16/09/2011   45    13/12/2017
```

My logic is to grab to add the `terms` (currently integer) to the
`date_given` as months to have a presumed finished date in a `cte` then grab another subtraction between that date and the `given-date` to have the result in months so I can the earlies and the lates.

I am trying the below but without success:

```
select date_given + interval 'terms month'
from Student_loan
```

How would I add that integer to the date and have a number of months or even subtract the two dates in my table and return a number of month?

Comment: In `interval 'terms month'` terms is just a string, not a field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make_interval()`

```
select date_given + make_interval(months => terms)
from student_loan
```

Alternatively multiply a one month interval with the value of the column:

```
select date_given + terms * interval '1 month'
from student_loan
```

---

> or even subtract the two dates in my table and return a number of month?

Just subtract them, the result of that is the number of days as both columns are (or at least seem to be) `date` values:

```
select last_paymnt - date_given as num_days
from student_loan
```

Comment: what if I want the number of months@

Comment: Well, "the number of months" is quite a volatile number. As the length of a month varies and also depends on the two dates that get subtracted. The best would be to cast both dates to `timestamp` then subtract them. The result of that is a an ìnterval`. The question is: what exactly do you want to do with that "number of months"?

Comment: Because the terms are in months. It would be easier to compare those two

Comment: So assume the difference is 29 days. Is that less than a month, exactly one month or more than one month?

Comment: I believe you are right. But I would not be able to determine which loans were paid early or late as the only thing that helps there is the terms that are in months

Comment: As I said: subtract the dates as timestamps. Then compare that difference with the interval created from the `terms` values (e.g. `make_interval()`)